# Object initialization and object factories in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, initialization, factory-pattern

I'm quite new to c++ development and design and so I apologize in advance in my question is vague or poorly structured.  I have several distinct and unrelated hierarchies in my code and I would like to use a generic factory as described and implemented by Alexandrescu to instantiate objects from these hierarchies .
   The part I am having difficulty with is the initialization phase.  The classes have very different initialization needs.  Sometimes the data needed for initialization can be looked up from storage (DB) and in those cases I can encapsulate the initialization procedure in some Init() method of the specific class.  But other times the data is known only locally an the moment of instantiation and needs to be passed to the object manually.  I'm struggling to come up with a uniform way to do this.  Does anyone have any inputs on approaching problems of this kind? 
Thanks

Comment: Alexandrescu is also a fan of policies, so you could have an allocation policy for your factory. However, if the concrete allocation need depends on runtime data, then I guess you can't get around a runtime-switching allocator. Maybe register a collection of allocator callbacks...

Comment: simply don't use factories (to avoid these problems). factories can solve some problems but they're very seldom actually needed

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Could you explain what you mean by "runtime-switching allocator" please.

Comment: @Stas: It's not very clear from your description what your actual problem is. But suppose you need to allocate memory for a new object, but you can only determine at runtime whether you take the memory from, say, a pool, or from malloc. Then you need an allocator that takes a parameter and determines based on that (e.g. by looking up a callback) how to obtain the memory. It's hard to see how this would be good design, but your description is extremely vague...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are hurtling down the *Over-Engineering* highway... head first.

Factories are seldom required, and no two Factories are alike (as you noticed).

It is useless to try and provide a base class for all your Factories, because this base class will have no clear semantic. What does it build ? `Bird`s ? `Car`s ? They are unrelated... `Object`s ? This is not Java!

If you wish to use Factories (for some reason), then a `Factory` should produce **1** kind of objects, all deriving from a common base class. If you have several kinds of objects, then you will need several kinds of Factories.

And if you find the Factory code repetitive, use a template to hoist the common code.

Answer (score 0):

If I guessed correctly, your problem is that you don't know how to pass different sets of arguments to your factory methods. If so it is, I can advise you to create one more hierarchy/ Let's call it FactoryHelper. The concrete class of this hierarchy will contain spesific data for instanciation of your concrete classes, for example FactoryHelperA for ConcreteProductA will contain a string and FactoryHelperB for ProductB will contain int. An abstact method of your factory must accept abstract base class - FactoryHelper as an argument. Concrete methods of your factory will cast this argument to concrete FactoryHelperA or FactoryHelperB and get specefic data for instanciation of specefic Product

But it's not very good design. I guess you're trying to use factory methods the wrong way.